# How to initialize viewHolder in RecyclerView adapter for Android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How should I initialize viewHolder? I have this error:
What I want to do is to get selected item in recyclerView but without using onClick method. When I get this selected item I need to show Toast message. Item is data class.

> Process: com.pors.coopreaderlast, PID: 7862
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewHolder has not been initialized
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaAdapter.getViewHolder(PolozkaAdapter.kt:18)
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaAdapter.getCurrentItem(PolozkaAdapter.kt:46)
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaActivity.onStart(PolozkaActivity.kt:213)

this is for line where viewHolder is set in Adapter:
lateinit var viewHolder: PolozkaViewHolder

This is Adapter

```
class PolozkaAdapter(val chosen_item: Int, private val listener: OnItemClickListener): ListAdapter<Polozka, PolozkaAdapter.PolozkaViewHolder>(DiffCallback()){
    var selectedItemPosition: Int = chosen_item
    lateinit var viewHolder: PolozkaViewHolder

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PolozkaViewHolder {
        val binding = PolozkyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        viewHolder = PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
        return viewHolder
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PolozkaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
        if (selectedItemPosition == position){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DA745A"))
        } else{
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }
    fun getCurrentItem(): Polozka = super.getItem(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)    

    inner class PolozkaViewHolder(private val binding: PolozkyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener{
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    val item = getItem(position)
                    if (item != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(item, position)                        
                    }
                }
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)                
                selectedItemPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)
            }            
        }

        fun bind(polozkaPolozka: Polozka){
            binding.apply {
                tvKDE.text = polozkaPolozka.znacky
                tvREG.text = polozkaPolozka.reg
                tvVB.text = polozkaPolozka.veb.toString()  
            }
        }
        }
    }
    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(polozkaDoklad: Polozka, position: Int)        
    }
    class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Polozka>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Polozka, newItem: Polozka) =
            oldItem.pvp06pk == newItem.pvp06pk
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Polozka, newItem: Polozka) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

This is onStart method but it can be in onCreate method also.

```
 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        
        val polozkaAdapter = PolozkaAdapter(idPositionItem, this)
        val selectedItem = polozkaAdapter.getCurrentItem()        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `polozkaAdapter.getCurrentItem()` in the `onStart()` method of your activity. At this point no items exist in your adapter so the `latenit var viewHolder` has not yet been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateViewHolder` should always return a new instance of a `ViewHolder`, not a single instance.

Comment: How should I do it? How to return new instance of a ViewHolder?