# Error when initialize viewHolder in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How should I initialize viewHolder? I have this error:
What I need to do is to get selected item in recyclerView but without using onClick method. When I get this selected item I need to show Toast message. Item is data class. Is it possible to pass some value from adapter to activity? Like I need to pass actual items from Data Class.

> Process: com.pors.coopreaderlast, PID: 7862
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewHolder has not been initialized
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaAdapter.getViewHolder(PolozkaAdapter.kt:18)
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaAdapter.getCurrentItem(PolozkaAdapter.kt:46)
> at com.pors.coopreaderlast.features.polozka.PolozkaActivity.onStart(PolozkaActivity.kt:213)

this is for line where viewHolder is set in Adapter:
lateinit var viewHolder: PolozkaViewHolder

This is Adapter

```
class PolozkaAdapter(val chosen_item: Int, private val listener: OnItemClickListener): ListAdapter<Polozka, PolozkaAdapter.PolozkaViewHolder>(DiffCallback()){
    var selectedItemPosition: Int = chosen_item
    lateinit var viewHolder: PolozkaViewHolder

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PolozkaViewHolder {
        val binding = PolozkyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        //return PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
        viewHolder = PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
        return viewHolder
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PolozkaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
        if (selectedItemPosition == position){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DA745A"))
        } else
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }
    fun getCurrentItem(): Polozka = super.getItem(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return super.getItemId(position)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount()
    }
    inner class PolozkaViewHolder(private val binding: PolozkyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener{
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    val item = getItem(position)
                    if (item != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(item, position)                        
                    }
                }
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)                
                selectedItemPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)
            }            
        }
        fun bind(polozkaPolozka: Polozka){
            binding.apply {                
                tvREG.text = polozkaPolozka.reg
                tvVB.text = polozkaPolozka.veb.toString()                
            }
        }        
    }
    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(polozkaDoklad: Polozka, position: Int)    
    }
    class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Polozka>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Polozka, newItem: Polozka) =
            oldItem.pvp06pk == newItem.pvp06pk
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Polozka, newItem: Polozka) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

This is onCreate method but it can be in onCreate method also.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityPolozkaBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        idPositionItem = intent.getIntExtra("positionItem",0)
        val itemAdapter = PolozkaAdapter(idPositionItem, this)
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.apply {
                adapter = itemAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ItemActivity)
            }
            itemViewModel.getall(index,idExp.toString() ).observe(this@PolozkaActivity){
                itemAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }
        val selectedItem = itemAdapter.getCurrentItem()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reg vybrane polozky je ${selectedItem.reg}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

I have similar question here: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70281159/2746995) but here I use binding.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this exception is that `viewHolder` has not been initalized at the moment you want to access it. And since it's a `lateinit var`, it expects to be initialized every time you access it. (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables)

Instead of using a `lateinit var` for `viewHolder`, you can return the instance you created in the `onCreateViewHolder()` so no need to have an extra field in the adapter for it.

I believe you use `viewHolder` to find the selected item. In that case I suggest using a boolean (for instance you can name it `selected`) in your model object `Polozka` to indicate if the item is selected or not. And in you `getCurrentItem()` method I would write `getCurrentList().find { it.selected }` to find the currently selected item. In this case you need to update your list every time you select a new item and mark only that as selected.

```
class PolozkaAdapter(private val listener: OnItemClickListener): ListAdapter<Polozka, PolozkaAdapter.PolozkaViewHolder>(DiffCallback()){
 
    lateinit var viewHolder: PolozkaViewHolder

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PolozkaViewHolder {
        val binding = PolozkyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PolozkaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
        if (currentItem.selected){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DA745A"))
        } else
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }
    fun getCurrentItem(): Polozka = currentList.find { it.selected }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return super.getItemId(position)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount()
}

//Model object would look like
data class Polozka(
    val selected: Boolean,
    //rest of the fields
)
```

And in the observe you should do it like this.

```
itemViewModel.getall(index,idExp.toString() ).observe(this@PolozkaActivity){
                // mark the item selected
                val updatedList = it.mapIndexed { index, item ->
                    if (index == idPositionItem) {
                        item.copy(selected = true)
                    } else {
                        item
                    }
                }
                itemAdapter.submitList(updatedList)
            }
        }
        val selectedItem = itemAdapter.getCurrentItem()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reg vybrane polozky je ${selectedItem.reg}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

And every time a new item gets selected you need to update your list.

Comment: This looks great. But how do I update my list to get not selected items to false?